# Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: jsp, tomcat

i am getting below exception and tomcat hangs and my services are down.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.search_005fresult_jsp._jspService(search_005fresult_jsp.java:86)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:384)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:276)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:216)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:634)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:445)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Sep 29, 2010 2:57:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationC
```

Comment: [Stop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) writing Java code in JSP and it'll improve your life as developer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to call a method on an object that is `null`

See, on line 86 of:

> /path/to/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/yourAppName/org/apache/jsp/search_005fresult_jsp.java

Answer (score 0):

you are referencing a variable that is null in your `search_005fresult.jsp` which is causing an error in the compiled servlet file on **line 86**.

I would use a debugger and step through to find where the null variable is, or just look at the jsp it should relatively obvious.

Comment: That's line 86 of the compiled servlet file not the source JSP

Comment: this is  not jsp ,built by apache

Comment: @josek true, I edited. @user it is jsp whether or not you wrote it on it is another question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to consider what you are doing at this line where the nullpointer is located.

I just had a similar issue where there is a ServletContextListener that stores a object that I tried to access later on - but when the server was restarted the contextInitialized where the object is set was not called - so I had a similar nullpointer when I tried accessing the object that was no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Comment: This has nothing to do with the original question.

Answer (score -1):

### open this file tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/yourAppName/org/apache/jsp/search_005fresult_jsp.java and then go to line no 86. check object or String variable , use not null check . ex. if(Object!=null){ //use this .. //your code }